# Object with same key already exists in objectstatemanager

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, objectstatemanager

Lots of questions about this error, and yet I cant figure out my problem (maybe i need some more of the theory around this).

I'm gettin the "Object with same key already exists in objectstatemanager" error and what im trying to do is so simple, I just have a Edit View for client, which has a list of Phones. As sson as the user hits the Save button, I just wrap everything with Json and send it to the controller with Ajax.

On the Controller, im supposed to check which phones on the list sent i should update, insert as news and delete.

So here's the important part of the code (and the one that throws the exeception mentioned):

```
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                foreach (var tel in propModel.Proprietario.Telefones)
                {
                    //Updates
                    TelefoneProprietario telToEdit = null;
                    if (tel.IDTelefoneProprietario.HasValue)
                        telToEdit = db.TelefonesProprietarios.Find(tel.IDTelefoneProprietario);
                    if (telToEdit != null)
                    {
                        db.Entry(tel).State = EntityState.Modified; << Exception HERE!!!
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //Inserts
                        db.TelefonesProprietarios.Add(tel);
                    }
                }

                if (propModel.Proprietario.IDProprietario.HasValue)
                {
                    var prop = db.Proprietarios.Find(propModel.Proprietario.IDProprietario);
                    prop.LoadLists();
                    foreach (var telDel in prop.Telefones)
                    {
                        //Deletes
                        if (propModel.Proprietario.Telefones.Find(t => t.IDTelefoneProprietario == telDel.IDTelefoneProprietario) == null)
                        {
                            db.TelefonesProprietarios.Remove(telDel);
                        }
                    }
                }

                db.Entry(propModel.Proprietario).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();

                return Json(new { Success = 1, IDProprietario = propModel.Proprietario.IDProprietario, ex = "" });
            }
```

Any help or suggestions?

And to make it even worst: I took the line throwing the exception out, just to test the rest of the code, and on the last line before the SaveChanges, it throws another exception:

```
The relationship between the two objects cannot be defined because they are attached to different ObjectContext objects.
```

UPDATE:

I manage to solve part of the problem re-writing the routine above in another form, like this:

```
                if (prop.IDProprietario.HasValue)
                {
                    //Separete updates/inserts from deletes
                    List<int?> dbTels = db.TelefonesProprietarios
                                    .Where(dt => dt.IDProprietario == prop.IDProprietario)
                                    .Select(dt => dt.IDTelefoneProprietario)
                                    .ToList();

                    List<int?> postedTels = prop.Telefones
                        .Select(pt => pt.IDTelefoneProprietario)
                        .ToList();

                    List<int?> deletedTels = dbTels
                        .Except(postedTels).ToList();

                    //Perform deletes
                    foreach (var delTelId in deletedTels)
                    {
                        if (delTelId.HasValue)
                        {
                            TelefoneProprietario delTel = db.TelefonesProprietarios
                                .Where(dt => dt.IDProprietario == prop.IDProprietario && dt.IDTelefoneProprietario == delTelId)
                                .Single();

                            db.Entry(delTel).State = EntityState.Deleted;
                        }
                    }

                    //Perform insert and updates
                    foreach (var tel in prop.Telefones)
                    {
                        if (tel.IDTelefoneProprietario.HasValue)
                        {
                            db.Entry(tel).State = EntityState.Modified;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            db.Entry(tel).State = EntityState.Added;
                            tel.IDProprietario = (int)prop.IDProprietario;
                        }
                    }

                    db.Entry(prop).State = EntityState.Modified;
                }
                else 
                {
                    db.Proprietarios.Add(prop);
                }
                db.SaveChanges();
```

Only problem left now is for deleting a Proprietario instance (cause it has a List of TelefoneProprietario and the TelefoneProprietario has a reference back to the Proprietario that ownes it. This cenario causes a "relationship between the two objects cannot be defined because they are attached to different ObjectContext objects" as widely discussed here in SO... Trying to figure out a solution, so if you can point me something...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do this: `db.Entry(tel).State = EntityState.Modified;`

**tel** object is just a object model you pass in, right?

So EF context at this time does not keep track of any object which has the **same key** with **tel's key** in this case **IDTelefoneProprietario**

Therefore if you set the object state to Modified then **SaveChanges()** EF will throw error.

Do this instead:

```
if (telToEdit != null)
{
    // Do apply all the changes from 'tel' to 'telToEdit' object here
    ...
    db.Entry(telToEdit).State = EntityState.Modified; // No Exception I hope :)
}
```

Hope it makes sense.

Comment: Yes, it makes sence. Unfortunatelly Im still having some problems to understand the hole EF thing (and exactly how it works). At this point (and in sync with what you told me) I re-coded the hole method. Now it's like the one I just pasted on the question (above), and it's working. The problem is in the deletion routine (since my Proprietario class have a list of TelefoneProprietario and a TelefoneProprietario have a reference to its Proprietario, i'm getting the "relationship between the two objects cannot be defined because they are attached to different ObjectContext objects" exception)...