# How do I update the entity with the foreign key?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have two entities as follows:

```
 public class Package
     {
            public int PackageId { get; set; }
            public int BusinessId { get; set; }

             public string Name { get; set; }
     }
```

And

```
   public class Business
     {


    public int BusinessId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    }
```

I want to edit the Package and update the related Business entity.  I’ve been trying the following:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Package package)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

                db.Packages.Attach(new Package { PackageId=package.PackageId
       });


                db.Entry(package).State = EntityState.Modified;

                db.SaveChanges();


            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        ViewBag.GenreId = new SelectList(db.Businesses , "BusinessId", "Name", package.BusinessId);
        return View(package);
    }
```

The code stops here with this message:

An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key.

I’ve been trying the example like the one here... http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2009/03/16/foreign-keys-in-the-entity-framework.aspx... but I’m not sure what I’m doing wrong.

How do I update the entity with the foreign key?

Comment: This question is quite similar to this question posted 2 months ago. Kindly look at this.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13311652/object-with-same-key-already-exists-in-objectstatemanager

Answer (score 0):

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(int packageId)
{

    var package = db.Packages.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Id == packageId);
    if(TryUpdateModel(package))
    {
        ...
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried it and got an error message of:The entity type DbQuery`1 is not part of the model for the current context.

Comment: @CloudyKooper Sorry, I Edited my question, try it